# UIAlert Dialogue boxes are animating in very bizarrely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I've got an odd thing happening.  I have my View and then I have a Scroll View that I animate in with a button.  Everything works fine but the native dialogue boxes start picking up weird animations? (See GIF Example)  When I comment out my code and run - this doesn't happen anymore.  Below is the problem code. Any idea of what I need to change to make it not affect the iOS UIAlerts?  Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```
- (IBAction)openMenu:(id)sender {


    if (draw1 == 0) {

        draw1 = 1;

        [openMenu setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIScrollView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIScrollView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 100);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(690, 195, 60, 60);

        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];

        [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

    } else {


        draw1 = 0;

        [openMenu setTitle:@"Open" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIScrollView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIScrollView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 768, 100);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(690, 95, 60, 60);

        [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The system dialog is trying to display at the center of its parent view, but you’re changing the bounds of the parent view as that’s happening. Make sure your view is finished animating before you allow the UIActionSheet to appear.

Comment: How would i do that? set a removeAllAnimations on my actionsheet? Not quite sure I follow.

Comment: What is triggering the UIActionSheet to appear? Is it user interaction or your code? In the latter case, don’t trigger the sheet until your animations are finished. In the former case, disable the user interaction until the animations are finished.

Comment: I have a - (void)actionSheet: that pops up the save (first in gif) and a -(void) alertView: that exits the view (second in gif). I believe that all of my animations are "finished" before pressing either. I don't see my scroll view animating at all when I click these buttons?